# Deploying Spring boot with Spring data jpa in AWS lambda

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-data-jpa, amazon-rds

I have created a spring boot application with spring data JPA that should connect with a RDS instance,i have api's exposed which will deo CRUD basically I have provided the DB connection details as below in application.yml file,

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: url
    username: username
    password: password
```

I have added the below dependency too,

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-springboot2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have my initializer class as below,

```
private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;
    static {
        try {
            
            if (handler == null) {
                LambdaContainerHandler.getContainerConfig().setInitializationTimeout(60_000);
                handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(Application.class);



                handler.onStartup(servletContext -> {
                    FilterRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addFilter("CognitoIdentityFilter",
                            CognitoIdentityFilter.class);
                    registration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "/*");
                });
            }
        } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
            // if we fail here. We re-throw the exception to force another cold start
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot application", e);
        }
    }
```

Everything seems to be proper, i have created a lambda from AWS console, the have also packing the jar by using below assembler,

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
    <id>lambda-package</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <!-- copy runtime dependencies with some exclusions -->
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}${file.separator}lib</directory>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>tomcat-embed*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
        <!-- copy all classes -->
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}${file.separator}classes</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <outputDirectory>${file.separator}</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Iam using below, plugin

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>shaded-jar</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactSet>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>org.apache.tomcat.embed:*</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </artifactSet>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>assembly-zip</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- select and copy only runtime dependencies to a temporary lib folder -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                    <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>zip-assembly</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                                    <descriptors>
                                        <descriptor>src${file.separator}assembly${file.separator}bin.xml</descriptor>
                                    </descriptors>
                                    <attach>false</attach>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


</project>
```

A zip is created and am uploading the zip to and providng the s3 URL to Lambda function.

After that i have created a API gateway HTTP API and chosen the integration as the previously created Lambda. If i try to access the APi am getting, {"message":"Internal Server Error"}

In cloudwatch logs, i could see,

[image]

It is getting struck at establising DB connection. I have chosen execution rule as Admin for lambda and provided same VPC as RDS, but no luck, kndly let me know a solution for this.

Comment: To check connection, you can use [VPC Reachability Analyzer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-insights-analyzes-reachability-and-visibility-in-vpcs/) : Create and analyze path with Source type Network Interfaces and Source as Network Interface Id of the your AWS Lambda. Furthermore, select Destination type as Network Interfaces and Destination as network Interface Id of the AWS RDS DB Instance. Put Destination port as the database communication port you are using, keep Protocol as TCP. Note*: It takes few minutes for completion of this path analysis.

Comment: So you suspect a connectivity issue? I can access the DB from my local machine, and its is accessible publicly. Is there any sample repo you can share that has spring data jpa connected to RDS deployed to Lambda

Comment: Increasing lambda timeut fixed this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing Lambda timeout fixed this issue.
Added the below lines too,

LambdaContainerHandler.getContainerConfig().setInitializationTimeout(60_000);
handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(Application.class);